# Multiple ImageUpload in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have problem in uploading multiple Image in codeigniter

myview

```
<tr>
                <td> Picture</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple /></input></td>
            </tr>
```

and my model

```
function multi_upload_files($imagepath=''){

     $number_of_files_uploaded = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

       for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files_uploaded; $i++) {
      $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];


    $config['upload_path'] = $imagepath;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 900;
    $config['max_width'] = 2024;
    $config['max_height'] = 1068;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

     $fileData = $this->upload->data();
     $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
     $images[]= $uploadData[$i]['file_name'];
     return $images;
    }  }
```

I have testing it and the problem this code just read my upload Image just 1 image, not equal to number of my file that just upload (for ex: 2 image)

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010082/codeigniter-update-new-image-in-database-column-without-replace-old-one

Comment: Have you increase the limit of file upload (no of files and size of file) in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following lines, you just overwrote everything with the first item in the array. Thus, only the first item is processed and the rest are overwritten. Plus, you have a return at the end of the loop. The function returns before the loop can finish.

```
  $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
  $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
  $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
  $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
  ...
  return $images;
```

Comment: if I return variabel outside the looping, I have error Uninitialized string offset: 2

Comment: good. that is one bug that needed to be fixed. now, that error refers to the first bug i mentioned. you are overwriting all of the images with the first image as i pointed out above. not sure what the purpose of that is but if it is not useful as it seems, removing it should fix it.

Comment: so what I must to remove to fix it?

Comment: remove those first 5 lines that i have in my answer

Comment: I try remove that line, it can't fix my problem, and now i have  more problem that i can't upload more than 2 files, it give error  Uninitialized string offset: 2. it point to 5 lines

Answer (score 0):

You miss two things.

First,variable `$imagepath` is not defined.

Second, You miss to load `upload` libaray.

So,Solution is here try it.Hope it will works...

```
function multi_upload_files($imagepath=''){
         $data = array();
         $number_of_files_uploaded = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

           for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files_uploaded; $i++) {
          $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
          $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
          $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
          $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
          $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

        $imagepath = 'Define upload path here';
        $config['upload_path'] = $imagepath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 900;
        $config['max_width'] = 2024;
        $config['max_height'] = 1068;
        //Load library first then use
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
         if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
          {
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
            $images[]= $uploadData[$i]['file_name'];
          }  
         return $images;
    }
```

Comment: I still have problem with your code, the problem just read one image after I   upload multiple image

Comment: Take the reference from here http://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-upload-multiple-files-images/